# HttpHostConnectException Connection to http://192.168.1.33 refused

Tags: php, android, json

My computer ip is 192.168.1.33. I want to access JOSN file returned by http://192.168.1.33//mla.php.
I'm connecting my android phone,and I'm not using any emulators.I'm using AsyncTask to get data in SplashScreenActivity.I have changed apache's configuration file to allow all,even phpmyadmin page's configuration file to allow all devices.I'm parsing this URL in JSONParser class.How to access http://192.1638.1.33/mla.php rom my android phone?

```js
//activity_splash.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
 
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgLogo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/splash" />
 
   
</RelativeLayout>
```

```css
//JSONParser.java
package com.example.hellomla;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.util.Log;
public class JSONParser {
  static InputStream is = null;
  static JSONObject jObj = null;
  static String json = "";
  // constructor
  public JSONParser() {
  }
  public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {
    // Making HTTP request
    try {
      // defaultHttpClient
      DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
      HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
      HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
      HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
      is = httpEntity.getContent();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
          is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      String line = null;
      while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line + "\n");
      }
      is.close();
      json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }
    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
      jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
      Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }
    // return JSON String
    return jObj;
  }
}
```

```html
//SpalshScreenActivity.java

package com.example.hellomla;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class SplashScreen extends Activity {
 ArrayList<String> consts = new ArrayList<String>();//array to store constituency names
 ArrayList<String> cids = new ArrayList<String>();//array to store constituency ids
 ArrayList<String> cps=new ArrayList<String>();//array to store constituency population
 ArrayList<String> conslks=new ArrayList<String>();//array to store loksabha constituency
 ArrayList<String> conmp=new ArrayList<String>();
 ArrayList<String> mlaname=new ArrayList<String>();
 ArrayList<String> mlaparty=new ArrayList<String>();
 ArrayList<String> mlaage=new ArrayList<String>();
 ArrayList<String> mlaedu=new ArrayList<String>();
 ArrayList<String> mlaaddress=new ArrayList<String>();
 ArrayList<String> mlaemail=new ArrayList<String>();
 ArrayList<String> mlaphone=new ArrayList<String>();
 ArrayList<String> mlawebsite=new ArrayList<String>();
 ArrayList<String> mlaabout=new ArrayList<String>();
 ArrayList<String> mlaphoto=new ArrayList<String>();


 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

  new JSONParse().execute();
 }

 private class JSONParse  extends AsyncTask<String,String,JSONObject> {
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
  @Override
  protected void onPreExecute() {
   super.onPreExecute();
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(SplashScreen.this);
             pDialog.setMessage("Getting Data ...");
             pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
             pDialog.setCancelable(true);
             pDialog.show();
   // before making http calls         

  }

  @Override
  protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
   JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
   JSONObject jsonObj = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl("http://192.168.1.33/constitncy.php");

   
   return jsonObj;
   }
  protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject jsonObj) {
   //super.execute(result);
   // After completing http call
   // will close this activity and lauch main activity
   pDialog.dismiss();
   try {
    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("constituencies");
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
     // add constituency name to consts array

     consts.add(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("conName"));
     // add constituency id to cids array

     cids.add(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("conID"));
     cps.add(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("conPopulation"));
     conslks.add(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("conLokSabha"));
     conmp.add(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("conMP"));
     mlaname.add(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("mlaName"));
     mlaparty.add(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("mlaParty"));
     mlaage.add(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("mlaAge"));
     mlaedu.add(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("mlaEdu"));
     mlaaddress.add(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("mlaAddress"));
     mlaemail.add(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("mlaEmail"));
     mlaphone.add(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("mlaPhone"));
     mlawebsite.add(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("mlaWebsite"));
     mlaabout.add(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("mlaAbout"));
     mlaphoto.add(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("mlaPhoto"));
    }

   } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
   Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
   i.putExtra("cIDS", cids);
   i.putExtra("cNAMES", consts);
   i.putExtra("cPLTN",cps);
   i.putExtra("cLKS",conslks);
   i.putExtra("cMP",conmp);
   i.putExtra("mNAME",mlaname);
   i.putExtra("mPARTY",mlaparty);
   i.putExtra("mAGE",mlaage);
   i.putExtra("mEDU",mlaedu);
   i.putExtra("mADRS",mlaaddress);
   i.putExtra("mEML",mlaemail);
   i.putExtra("mPHNE",mlaphone);
   i.putExtra("mWBST",mlawebsite);
   i.putExtra("mABT",mlaabout);
   i.putExtra("mPHTO",mlaphoto);
   startActivity(i);

   // close this activity
   finish();
  }

  
 }




}
```

Comment: Check your permissions in your manifest file

Comment: check your firewall + check that your device is on the same network as your pc